# TASK :Keep some thread work ,get data from Datagridview

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, task

Example,how can i keep 10 threads working still to finish,if one or more thread finished,go ahead others task,still finish all the tasks.but just keep 10 thread working.

```
//While(index2<dataGridView.RowCount)    

   for (int i=0;i<10;i++)//keep 10 thread working

            //  t[index2] = new Task(() =>
              {

                  // startLink(index2);

              });
            // t[index2].Start();
            // t[index2].Wait()

//index2++; //dataGridView.Row number
```

Comment: who can give me idea?

Comment: If I just could understand what you are trying to accomplish.. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: thanks peter,example :i have more than 1000 websites in   (dataGridView1.Rows[index2].Cells[0].Value.) i want to get all these website link, use task to keep some thread to emplement. if i have 10 thread running , the num02 thread is finished , then only have 9 thread working . how can still keep 10 threads work, and auto to take num11 from datagridview.

Comment: after all the websites finished ,then the 10 threads all finished. it is difficult for me , how still keep 10 threads working , to finish all.

Comment: i have tested  SemaphoreSlim;not success, cos the sequence question. can not take datagridvie data  from top to bottom one by one.

Comment: wish you understand my meaning, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

C# limits the amount of tasks executed by your program by the amount of processors your pc has (this is no conincidence).

You can reed more about limiting concurrency here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.100).aspx

basically you'd need to implement your own task Schedular to only run 10 tasks at a time.

This way you can schedule unlimited amount of tasks, but the TaskScheduler only runs 10 at a time.

## Option 2

1. is to start 10 tasks
2. await Any (until one is done)
3. schedule a new task. and wait again until one is done.

But remember this option 2. only the amount of tasks are executed as the amount of processors you have. Because this is the default way scheduled tasks are executed. (you actually schedule a task whenever you say `Tas.Run(...)` instead of directly running it.

## Big tasks

If you have big tasks and 1 thread is already finished before the rest (i read out of comment). Then divide your big tasks up into small tasks (or make new tasks inside a task). These new tasks themselves will then be scheduled and run over all the tasks runners.